# Attaching caned webbing to cabinet doors

Tags: glue, cabinetry

I'm making a cabinet and using cane webbing in the doors. I need to adhere the webbing to a stained ply for the backing.

I can't seem to find an answer on what to use for glue. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I believe that usually you would route a thin groove around the area to be caned, then push the caning into the groove with some sort of bead that will hold it in place. I'm reasonably certain that it isn't actually glued in. However, there's no expertise or experience behind this, so I'd suggest waiting for an actual answer.

Comment: Hi Tim, welcome to StackExchange. *"Can't seem to find an answer on what to use for glue"* There's a reason for that, it's because you don't normally glue webbing to a backing. In addition you're seeking to bond to a stained surface, which is also not something usually done (and it may in fact be impossible to do properly, since some stains *can't* be glued to which is why one is so careful to keep them off joint surfaces if pre-finishing work prior to assembly). Based on this do you want to revise your plan?

Comment: I would love to revise my plan but people want what they want... the customer didn't want to see through it. I don't really have a choice in the matter.  Did some test pieces and I believe contact cement could be the answer... thanks for responding!  If anyone else has any ideas,  I'm all ears!

Comment: Apologies. I wasn't clear. I didn't mean only revise to remove a backing (although I thought that would be a possible option), this also includes revise how you would back a woven panel. I'm sure this would be best not glued down all over. My main hesitation being that *you'll see glue* through every one of the gaps in the pattern. In addition this has a glued surface exposed to air, which I think rules out contact cement, no? (Permanently tacky.) So instead of glueing it to the face of the panel you might glue the edges only (hidden by the frame itself, or mouldings) or even around the back

Comment: BTW you should include anything that is a customer requirement or similar in this (and any future) Questions as it's a vital constraint for potential respondents to know, preventing them from suggestions something along the lines of "why not just stretch it around an inset frame instead?"

Comment: There are at least two Answers in these comments!

Answer (score 1):

Are you able to hide any part of the webbing on the edges? If so, I'd just use staples around the perimeter of the webbing. If the entire webbing is meant to be visible, this obviously is not an option.

I have seen people use Gorilla Contact Adhesive to use cane webbing over both wood and glass in situations where the entire webbing needs to be visible. It's especially important to get the clear glue because you don't want it to be the glue to be visible when it dries.

[image: Gorilla Glue Clear]

Let me know what you decide to do! I have a cane webbing project I'm going to do in a few weeks.

Comment: Welcome to WW.SE. Since that link will be dead in an internet minute, maybe you could present it with a little more context? [Edit] the Answer and maybe include some details about how this technoque did or did not work, or remove it altogether as it may not apply to the question at hand, which does not mention glass.

Comment: @jdv Thanks for the advice! I updated the response above^.